# Reverse Arabic string when printing the form

Tags: c#, string, reverse

My method, `printDocument`, prints the input in reverse order like the following string

> "ك - 8 - 12"

I want to print the numbers before letters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringFormat` and specify format flag to `DirectionRightToLeft` As the following:

```
using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("السيد {0}"), font, brush, location, format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `StringFormat` to make the direction of variable is `RightToLeft` and passed the instance of `StringFormat` to `e.Graphics.DrawString()`.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have more information to add to your question, then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22312751/edit) your post.

Comment: Sorry, but it solved my problem and reversed the string making numbers comes before letters , i couldn't write the reversed string here because it appears like the string in the question

Comment: @gunr2171 This answer seems fine to me, especially since it resolved his issue.